# How to manage a particular "order by" for get_search_query()?

Tags: query, search, sort, order

How to manage in the search.php file the order of a posts search query managed with the following code

```
<?php
echo sprintf(__('%s Zoekresultaten voor ', 'website'), $wp_query->found_posts);
echo get_search_query();

while (have_posts()) {
  the_post();
?>

  <article>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    <span class="datePost"><?php the_time('j-M-Y H:i'); ?></span>
  </article>
<?php
}
?>
```

Is it possible to chose a field to order the search results? My goal should be to sort them according the time of the post managed with the function `the_time('j-M-Y H:i');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parse_query action hook, and set the orderby and order paramenters.

```
function my_mod_search($query) {
    if ($query->is_search()) {
        $query->query_vars['order'] = 'ASC';
        $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'post_date';
    }
}

add_action('parse_query', 'my_mod_search');
```